# How Can I Send a "Copy" Command Using Python Subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to send a command prompt command using Python Subprocess. I haven't been able to get my code to send "\" in the command. I usually specify directions as:

```
"D:\\deneme\\1"
```

or

```
r"D\deneme\\1"
```

So, I tried both as:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["copy /b D:\\deneme\\1\\*.ts D:\\deneme\\1\\1.ts"])
```

But the string is sent as it is so I get the error, "FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified". I also tried using the unicode number (\u005C), but it also returns double "\". What should I do in this case?

Comment: the `subprocess` module receives the command as a list of parts, not as a strings string in a list. You should try: `subprocess.run(['copy', '/b', r'D:\deneme\1\*.ts', r'D:\deneme\1\1.ts'])`. I'm not a Windows user, but `copy` might need `shell=True` to be set. And BTW, there are direct options to copy something in Python.

Comment: shell=True did the job, thank you. If you add it as answer, I could flag it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system shell is try to find a command with the name `copy /b D:\\...`, not run `copy` with 3 arguments. Either drop the list:

```
subprocess.run("copy /b D:\\deneme\\1\\*.ts D:\\deneme\\1\\1.ts")
```

or pass a proper list containing the command name and its arguments as separate elements.

```
subprocess.run(["copy", "/b", "D:\\deneme\\1\\*.ts", "D:\\deneme\\1\\1.ts"])
```

Comment: Tried both, neither worked. And to make sure the directories are correct, I typed "copy /b D:\deneme\1\*.ts D:\deneme\1\1.ts" into shell and it works.